# How apply automation testing for drop down-search in selenium java eclips?

Tags: java, selenium

Here is the code for that I want automation:

```html
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-selection-class-dropdown-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selection-class-dropdown-container" title="Search">Search</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span>
```

Comment: 1- reformat your question so the html will be visible 2- show what you tried, this is not code generating service.

Comment: I have edit you can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working!!!

```
 Select mydrpdwn1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selection-division-dropdown")));
     mydrpdwn1.selectByVisibleText("division A");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectOption(text)
{
    IWebElement _webElement = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Name("ID of your dropdown"));
    SelectElement ddloptions = new SelectElement(_webElement);
    ddloptions.SelectByText(text);
}
```

To get the selected option from drop down:

```
public static string GetServiceUserDropdown()
{
    IWebElement _webElement = Drivers._driverInstance.FindElement(By.Name("Id of dropdown"));
    SelectElement selectedvalue = new SelectElement(_webElement);
    return selectedvalue.SelectedOption.Text;
}
```

Hope this helps. Code is in c#